# How to modify implicit GNUMake rules to compile files?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

GNUMake has implicit rules to compile certain file types, for instance, in my directory if I have a file `1.cpp`, and I write on terminal `make 1`, the following command gets executed:

```
g++     1.cpp   -o 1
```

All this happens without any `Makefile` in the directory, due to implicit `Make` rules. However, I am unable to figure out how to modify these rules for my benefit. For instance, if I need to compile my file like this:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -g -w -o 1 1.cpp
```

and for doing this, I want to run the command: `make 1`, it should do it. Also, it should be generic for any file, for instance I now create a file `2.cpp` and write `make 2`, it should compile it and produce the executable, even if there is no rule for `2` in my `Makefile`. 
Also, if I now go to another directory where this explicit rule has not been mentioned, it should compile according to the default implicit rules only. How to I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to `set` the variables used by the implicit rules in your environment

```
set CXXFLAGS="-std=c++14 -O2 -g -w"
```

If you only want this to apply to a single directory, then place a `Makefile` in the directory with the following

```
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++14 -O2 -g -w
```

Comment: But I want these flags to be local to my current directory only, and not anywhere in my system. Will this work?

Comment: @SahilArora Updated answer